# SQL query Get max numbers in a string

Tags: mysql, server, max

Is it possible to get the maximum number in a string like this with a MySql query?

"RANDOMTEXT$£ 070.00/180.25"

in this case it would be 80...
The number of numbers (sorry) in the string is variable, depending on a record that I have in another table.
The number maximum is 999.99

Thanks

Comment: It's possible to create a scalar function that does this.  Does it have to be able to handle decimals too, or is it integer values only?

Comment: Decimals too (xxx.xx)

Comment: Also, is there an expected upper-limit for the number? e.g., 999,999,999

Comment: Max of 2 decimal places?

Comment: If you need a SQL solution to this, then you should edit your original question to say as much.  Also include the info you added from your comments into your question.  Lastly, you've tagged this with both MySQL and SQL Server?, so which are you actually using?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: wouldn't you expect 180.25 as the result instead of 80?

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

You will need to parse the text into variables cast them to a numeric data type and then perform the comparison. If you plan to perform such task in multiple row, the task is better suited to be contained in a function.

Comment: and probably better suited to a non-db task.

Comment: Agreed.  Though, if @user6331675 requires it in SQL, then it's possible.  Solutions off of the top of my head would be slow and would not operate well on sets.

Comment: The parsing itself would be a headache, specially when i see "random text" in there >.<

Comment: Would it be easier if I rewrite the string in a json format?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with for SQL Server.  You can use the same logic in MySQL, though I don't know of a TRY_CAST function equivalent in MySQL.

Perhaps someone who knows MySQL syntax better than I can edit this?  The following query returns `999.00`.

```
DECLARE @String Varchar(1000) = 'kdsfjalkjdf389kljsafd3.02laksjfd6098;lksadjf0394a;lkjdf3.45.2klasjdf4.68;laksjf296kljsdf999skldjf689.78'
DECLARE @StringLen integer = LEN(@String)
DECLARE @Parser integer = 0
DECLARE @StringsTVP Table (
   Strings varchar(6)
)

WHILE @Parser < @StringLen - 1
BEGIN
   -- use max string length of 6, since the upper-limit is 999.99
   INSERT INTO @StringsTVP (Strings) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @Parser, 1)
   INSERT INTO @StringsTVP (Strings) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @Parser, 2)
   INSERT INTO @StringsTVP (Strings) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @Parser, 3)
   INSERT INTO @StringsTVP (Strings) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @Parser, 4)
   INSERT INTO @StringsTVP (Strings) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @Parser, 5)
   INSERT INTO @StringsTVP (Strings) SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @Parser, 6)
   SET @Parser = @Parser + 1
END;
SELECT MAX(TRY_CAST(Strings AS Decimal(5, 2))) AS MaxNumber
FROM @StringsTVP
```

Comment: For reusability, I would recommend turning this into a scalar-valued function where @String is fed in as a parameter.  It would `RETURN SELECT MAX(TRY_CAST(Strings AS Decimal(5, 2))) FROM @StringsTVP`

Comment: I also noticed that MySQL doesn't support table-valued parameters?  Thus, one should declare it as a 'temporary table' e.g., `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE StringsTable (Strings varchar(6));`